# How to print stream in page using jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am little bit confused. Actually I am getting data from server like this:

```
data
-------------
a
ab
abc
abcd...... and so on
```

Data is being returned in real time. It means data is being sent each second, again and again. So I need to show data only **abcd**

```
<div id="log">waiting...</div>

socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
     if(JSON.stringify(msg)!=null)
    $('#log').append('<p>'+JSON.stringify(msg[data])+'</p>')

};
```

But when I used this code it showing(response) like this.

```
a
ab
abc
abcd...
```

Every second this function call prints new from starting.

I need the output only in a straight line with

```
abcd...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .html instead of .append.....

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
 if(JSON.stringify(msg)!=null)
   $('#log').html('<p>'+JSON.stringify(msg[data])+'</p>')
};
```